# Show dates older than current date in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

In my sql statement I have an SQL statement which i need to show which customers return dates are overdue i.e. older than current date, so far my query looks like the following:

```
SELECT customers.firstname, items.itemname, CustEquipment.ReturnDate, customers.phonenumber
FROM items join
 CustEquipment
 on items.ItemId = CustEquipment.ItemId join
 customers 
 on CustEquipment.customerID=customers.customerID
```

This currently shows all customers and their return dates (along with other info i need) but i want to show the return dates which have gone past the current date, anyone care to point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the date comparison in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT customers.firstname, items.itemname, CustEquipment.ReturnDate, customers.phonenumber
FROM items join
     CustEquipment
     on items.ItemId = CustEquipment.ItemId join
     customers 
     on CustEquipment.customerID=customers.customerID
where ReturnDate <= trunc(sysdate);
```

I also adjusted your query to use correct `join` syntax.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't know why some Oracle experts write queries in old style joines? (without `join` syntax)?

Answer (score 0):

```
select C.Firstname,I.ItemName,CE.ReturnDate,C.PhoneNumber
from Items I
inner join CustEquipments CE
on 
CE.ItemID=I.ItemID
inner join Customers C
on 
C.CustomerID=CE.CustomerID
where 
convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)>convert(varchar(10),CE.ReturnDate,101)
```